# How to correct grid search?

Tags: matlab, svm, hyperparameters

Trying to find the optimal hyperparameters for my svm model using a grid search, but it simply returns 1 for the hyperparameters.

```
function evaluations = inner_kfold_trainer(C,q,k,features_xy,labels)

features_xy_flds = kdivide(features_xy, k);
labels_flds = kdivide(labels, k);

evaluations = zeros(k,3);

for i = 1:k

    fprintf('Fold %i of %i\n',i,k);

    train_data =  cell2mat(features_xy_flds(1:end ~= i));
    train_labels = cell2mat(labels_flds(1:end ~= i));
    test_data = cell2mat(features_xy_flds(i));
    test_labels = cell2mat(labels_flds(i));

    %AU1 
    train_labels = train_labels(:,1);
    test_labels = test_labels(:,1);


    [k,~] = size(test_labels);

    %train
    sv = fitcsvm(train_data,train_labels, 'KernelFunction','polynomial', 'PolynomialOrder',q,'BoxConstraint',C);
    sv.predict(test_data);

    %Calculate evaluative measures
    %svm_outputs = zeros(k,1);
    sv_predictions = sv.predict(test_data);


    [precision,recall,F1] = evaluation(sv_predictions,test_labels);
    evaluations(i,1) = precision;
    evaluations(i,2) = recall;
    evaluations(i,3) = F1;


end

save('eval.mat', 'evaluations');

end
```

an inner-fold cross validation function
and below the grid function where something seems to be going wrong

```
function [q,C] = grid_search(features_xy,labels,k)

% n x n grid
n = 3;

q_grid = linspace(1,19,n);
C_grid = linspace(1,59,n);

tic

evals = zeros(n,n,3);

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        fprintf('## i=%i, j=%i ##\n', i, j);
        svm_results = inner_kfold_trainer(C_grid(i), q_grid(j),k,features_xy,labels);
        evals(i,j,:) = mean(svm_results(:,:));
        % precision only
        %evals(i,j,:) = max(svm_results(:,1));

        toc
    end
end

f = evals;

% retrieving the best value of the hyper parameters, to use in the outer
% fold
[M1,I1] = max(f);
[~,I2] = max(M1(1,1,:));
index = I1(:,:,I2);
C = C_grid(index(1))
q = q_grid(index(2))

end
```

When I run `grid_search(features_xy,labels,8)` for example, I get C=1 and q=1, for any k(the no. of folds) value. Also features_xy is a 500*98 matrix.

Comment: you may want to alter your code a little to help us following it. There are a couple of redundant statements (e.g. `sv.predict()`), odd commands (e.g. `(:,:)`) and unnecessary complexity (e.g. I doubt that k-foldness is necessary to reproduce your code, same with `ti`, `toc`, or similar).

Comment: so this code is hard to follow without making those changes?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a minimal working example that includes a) dummy data and b) sharpens the code to an minimum number of lines. That would help and increase the probability that people read your issue and help

Comment: I think your max(f); line is getting the maximum accuracy value, so the value 1 makes sense in that regard. If you want to get the hyperparameters, you will need to return the hyperparameter values. These are probably somewhere in the sv variable, so I would consider including that in the function result value.